# Full-height fluid Layout with editable Textfield

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I have been pondering this riddle for years, and I can't believe such a simple layout isn't solved with a simple piece of html+css. So I'll pass this one on to you for the weekend ;-)

**Desired Result**

(mental model: notepad.exe...)

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| height depends on static content.                 |
| This Part always stays visible.                   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| height exactly fills up remaining height.         |
| this part (ONLY!) scrolls if content is longer!   |
| (this part will be contenteditable)               |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| height depends on static content.                 |
| This Part always stays visible.                   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Requirements:

- no javascript ('cause that is my current unsatisfactory solution)
- pure CSS + HTML
- as cross-browser compatible and gracefully degradable as possible (no flexbox!)
- The height of the header and footer is unknown ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3654818/1598477) sadly won't work).

**How can I do it?**

Comment: Looks like a flexbox layout, but the browser support is not *that* good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not like the answer, but the only way I know to meet all your criteria is by using a table for layout.

#### HTML

```
<table class="layout">
  <tr class="header">
    <td>Header goes here

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
          Content goes here.
        </div>
      </div>

  <tr class="footer">
    <td>Footer goes here
</table>
```

#### CSS

The table takes up the entire viewport:

```
.layout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Because the table has 100% height, it will stretch all rows as needed to meet the height.  This style prevents it from stretching the header and footer rows:

```
.header, .footer {
  height: 0px;
}
```

This style is needed for Firefox only:

```
tr {
  height: 100%;
}
```

In all browsers *except* IE, this style works on the `td`.  I've put it in a `div` so it will work with IE:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Now that we have a container with relative positioning, we can apply absolute positioning with 100% height and overflow on its content:

```
.content {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Tested in IE11, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari.

### Fiddle

Comment: very cool! I'll give it a try. Thank you for the thorough answer and working code!

Comment: You havent closed the `<tr>`s and `<td>`s in your HTML.

Comment: @RahulDesai, those are optional closing tags in HTML5:  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags.  In my experience, they're also unnecessary in HTML4.

Comment: Thank you @RickHitchcock. I used your code on [shrib.com](http://shrib.com), though I did implement it with CSS table coding (i.e. divs with display:table/table-row/table-cell) - just to make it look like it's not layout with tables ;-)

Comment: Hey, shrib.com is extremely cool.  Glad I could contribute a very small part to it.  And yes, divs make more sense, but I don't think those display options will work with IE prior to version 8.

Comment: Outch - you are right. Unfortunately, this doesn't only not render nicely, but it does not render the "save" button (in the "header") *at all*. Hm. If only there was a way to make this degrade more gracefully. I don't have a lot of mercy for the almost 2000 monthly users who are still behind ie8. but still, they should be able to save their notes. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The CSS in my table solution should work in IE7.  Does it fail as well  as your div solution?  2,000 monthly users is a real accomplishment on its own, but having 2,000 monthly users who are *behind* ie8 is unreal.

Comment: A few percent of a few hundred thousand users is still a big number ;-) I used [this very ugly fix](http://briancray.com/posts/target-ie6-and-ie7-with-only-1-extra-character-in-your-css) now...

Comment: That's new to me.  Your users probably care a *lot* more about functionality than CSS, so I wouldn't worry about prepending asterisks and underscores.  Glad you have a working solution!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66556/discussion-between-swiss-mister-and-rick-hitchcock).